# Problems with scraping coronatracker.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the table in https://www.coronatracker.com/analytics for a project. However, when i run my code it only scrapes the header of the table. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://www.coronatracker.com/analytics'
src = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')
table = soup.find('table',{"class" : "table-auto w-full"})
table_header = table.find('thead').find_all('th')

with open('results.csv','w',newline='')as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    header = []
    L1 = []
    for x in table_header:
        header.append(x.text)
    for y in header:
        L1.append(y.strip())
    for i, data in enumerate(L1):
        L1[i] = data.replace('\xa0', ' ')
        L1[i] = data.replace('\n',' ')
    writer.writerow(L1)
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        csvrow = []
        for a in row.find_all('td'):
            csvrow.append(a.text)
    for i in range(len(csvrow)):
        csvrow[i] = csvrow[i].replace('\n','')
    writer.writerow(csvrow)

f.close()
```

is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: [Enjoy](https://api.coronatracker.com/).

Comment: What table do you want?Data on this site load via Ajax it's why you can get it

Comment: im trying to get the table listing all the country stats at the bottom right of the analytics page

Comment: I give you URL for 3 tables. it returns JSON that easier parse for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data country:

```
https://api.coronatracker.com/v3/stats/worldometer/topCountry
```

Outbreak table:

```
https://api.coronatracker.com/v3/stats/worldometer/totalTrendingCases?limit=100
```

Top countries

```
https://api.coronatracker.com/v3/analytics/dailyNewStats
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of scraping technique works well only with website where html (with data )is rendered at server side itself. In your case, you are getting only headers in result because the site fetches data dynamically (when  html is loaded in browser) via some API call.

If you want scrape the data from this website you need a bit advanced method which uses selenium (which creates browser like environment).

The below medium article explain the steps for the same.

[Web Scraping with Python using Selenium](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/web-scraping-with-python-using-selenium-9a08b85b718a)